# How to set default date when using directive for datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

Below is my directive for having datepicker

```
app.directive("datepicker", function () {
return {
  restrict: "A",
  require: "ngModel",
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
    var updateModel = function (dateText) {
      scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
      });
    };
    var options = {
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      onSelect: function (dateText) {
        updateModel(dateText);
      }
    };
    elem.datepicker(options);
  }
}
});
```

I need the default value as current date(dd-mm-yy) in the textbox. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

add `defaultDate` to options

```
var options = {
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
  onSelect: function (dateText) {
    updateModel(dateText);
  }
};

elem.datepicker(options).datepicker("setDate", new Date());

updateModel(elem.val())
```